# Mobile database synchronization

Tags: android, ios, database, mobile

I have to write an app running on Android, iOS and desktops (I will probably use Titanium). This app has to maintain a database that is constantly synchronized between all devices and desktop (and maybe the web in the future).

Is there any tool/service allowing to do database synchronization very easily?

I want something where I write data locally on any device and data is automatically synchronized and merged using to all devices using the cloud.

Answer (score 3):

CouchDB is the way to go.  I'm working on a similar project right now.  iOS, Android, web client - they all need synchronization.  CouchDB has fantastic replication support that is all done over HTTP.  It's a thing of beauty.  Couchbase Mobile is still very much in a "developer preview" state, but progressing nicely.

You will have to handle potential update conflicts (CouchDB returns an HTTP 409 status code so you can handle it appropriately - based on your business requirements).

My only complaints so far is the boot up time of the CouchDB service and the size of the dependencies. If you can work around those problems, it might be a good solution for you.

Checkout more here: http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/couchbase-mobile

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I looked at it and it seems quite complicated to use even for a very simple task. My problem is that it doesn't support HTML5 (offline database) that in the future might be useful when writing HTML5 offline apps. Do you know of there is anything easier to use ?

Comment: It is a bit complicated, but significantly easier than a traditional SQL solution.  It's the easiest way I know how to do it.  If you're using HTML5, CouchDB starts to really shine.  It's APIs are HTTP, the data storage and transfer is all JSON.  That means it is significantly easier to consume the data on your web client.  HTML5 local storage is just key-value, so you can easily use your CouchDB key (_id) to reference it's stored value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mobeelizer. It is a solution, which offers you the complete sync infrastructure for mobile apps and allows you easily synchronize data between mobile and web or desktop application. There is also Titanium SDK for you. Here you can find more information http://docs.mobeelizer.com/display/doc/Titanium+References